# Google+ sharing - prefilling comment field

Tags: share, google-plus

Just a quick question.

I have a "Share with G+" button, which I integrated using easiest method:
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://...

Is there a way to insert text into a comment box?
If this cannot be done with method used here, can it be done with some other method?

Answer (score 0):

it should be helpful for you whether Google+ app is installed or not in your device so try it...

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    shareMediaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
    shareMediaButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(isGooglePlusInstalled())
                    {

                 PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    share.setText("write your message here.....!");
                    //share.addStream(selectedImage);
                    share.setType("text/plain");

                    startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(), 0);

        }else{
             Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(MainActivity.this)
              .setType("text/plain")
              .setText("write your message here.....!")

              .getIntent();

          startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
        }
        }

        public boolean isGooglePlusInstalled()
{
    try
    {
        getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.plus", 0 );
        return true;
    } 
    catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
    });
}
```